# Jupyter notebook desktop file: where is it?

Tags: jupyter

I was trying to follow this tutorial:
[Ubuntu 18.04 - open jupyter notebook with double click?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197891/ubuntu-18-04-open-jupyter-notebook-with-double-click)

But I can't find the `jupyter_notebook.desktop` at the location indicated...nor anywhere else!

Are we supposed to create this file?
If not, how to find it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wouldn't call that a tutorial, but it should be sufficient for this task. The poster of that question had indeed created their own `.desktop` file. In fact, they entered the actual commands needed to create such a file. The point of the answer was that the `Exec` line was incomplete, and that the file needed to be made executable.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: You have to create such desktop file manually, it [is not part of official deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/jupyter-notebook/filelist). What is your Ubuntu version? How Jupyter was installed?